# Is it possible to detect onomatopoeic basis in indigenous languages?

Tags: phonology, historical-linguistics, reference-request, origin-of-language, indian-languages

I'm about to study the ding dong vs the pooh pooh theories of the origin of language. I would like to make a poll with questions like "What emotions do you associate with the word "ka:men"?" and compare whether these answers are closer to the true representation of the word rather than answers to the questions like "Which of these objects would you guess "ka:men" to represent?".

Could you recommend any reading on this topic about studies done previously? And could you please give me any tips or advice about any potential mistakes I could possibly make when analyzing the data?

Thanks very much.

Feel free to reformulate the question if it doesn't sound clear to you.

Similar research: https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2016/09/160912161010.htm?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+sciencedaily%2Ftop_news%2Ftop_science+%28ScienceDaily%3A+Top+Science+News%29

Comment: In case you speak German, the following book is a nice introduction with lots of sources for further reading:

Volke, Stefan. 2007. Sprachphysiognomik. Grundlagen einer leibphänomenologischen Beschreibung der Lautwahrnehmung. Freiburg/München: Karl Alber.

Comment: I just noticed, you took that straight from Gretchen McCullens blog, so just read the recently published article on it, then: https://tmblr.co/ZuWOEv2C2-cZA

Comment: @aslakr Sorry, only words shorter than 8 letters :)

Comment: @aslakr I didn't take it from anywhere, but thanks for nice sources

Comment: I don't understand: what's "the true representation of the world" (and how do you know)?

Comment: @Teusz It's a typo, in his particular example he means: whether the emotions associated with the [Czech word] *kámen* are closer to the meaning *mountain/rock* than when people are asked otherwise. Btw I would just think of the ridiculous 'Hentai Kamen'-movie.

Comment: There's a well-known [Bouba/Kiki effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bouba/kiki_effect) (in an alternative version: maluma/takete). I would search for these words in Google Scholar and Google Books, I'm sure you'll find relevant studies.

Comment: @michau Yeah, I've heard about it but maybe I'd appreciate specific advice.

Comment: Is this is IPA, German or some other language? Could you add the IPA so as to be as clear as possible?

Answer (score 2):

Max Müller started the tradition of giving such silly names to theories of language origin in his 1861 [Lectures on the Science of Language](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/32856/32856-pdf.pdf?session_id=48d28028ef16b0b22c541b5131606e76e2c9bfde), which is available on line and which I recommend to you.

There is an interesting case of the influence of onomatopoeia on a phonological system in Stanley Newman's description of the wiyi verbs in *The Yawelmani dialect of Yokuts*.  Following Kuroda in *Yawelmani Phonology*, in these verbs alone the process of lowering the underlying long high vowels /i:/ /u:/ fails to occur.

Comment: Yeah, I know these, thank you. Maybe I'd rather appreciate specific research recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

@Probably, by the looks of it, you are in for a lot of primary research, though, I'd suggest you consider flipping it upside down, for the following reasons:

> I would like to make a poll with questions like "What emotions do you
>   associate with the word "ka:men"?" and compare whether these answers
>   are closer to the true representation of the word rather than answers
>   to the questions like "Which of these objects would you guess "ka:men"
>   to represent?".

You might have a hard time collecting a sufficiently large number of responses to validate your analysis. However, you could turn this around and look at how various languages express certain primitive / instinctive emotions. This wiki entry: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-linguistic_onomatopoeias has a fair amount of reliable data both for emotions and for things that have characteristic sounds - these could serve as a reference point for both theories as well as a pretty solid ground for your research hypothesis.

This is by no means supposed to imply not to conduct your experiment, but it might be a lot more tricky to conduct than you think. A fascinating read that would also be appropriate for the second half of your questions would be: https://books.google.hu/books?id=oEO0BQAAQBAJ

Even if you do not have the time to read it cover to cover, its overview of language origin theories would be a solid background. The experiment design sections may also be beneficial for your own poll setup.